# Amida Prayer in front of a handicapped man

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, handicap-disabled-impair

One is not allowed to sit in front of someone who is engaged in the amidah prayer (Brachot 31b, Shulchan Aruch 102:1).

1. If you are not saying the amida (not part of the minyan) and behind you a handicapped person is saying it in his wheelchair, are you allowed to sit in front of him? Perhaps this halacha does not apply since he is also sitting.
2. what about if you are part of the minyan and would like to take 3 steps backwards after finishing the amida and he is still in the middle of saying it?

Comment: I do not have sources, but I have davened in shuls where there were such handicapped people and there was no problem. However, there may also be a difference if each row has a table in front of it.

Comment: @sabbahillel See edits which clarify the case

Comment: Since the title is interrupting someone, is this about stepping back while the person behind you is davening? Please put in the actual halacha.

Comment: @sabbahillel where do you see "interrupting someone" in the title?

Comment: @ray I was searching for the online text of this halacha and found 102: Not to Interrupt Someone Who is Praying. Unfortunately, it only had the title and not an actual link.

Comment: to sit has a signification linked to the person who sit. not linked to other. Sitting is simbolic as saying something